# How to know which file is the median depending on its size

Tags: command-line

Theres 99 folders with different size. I would like to know which one of these folders is the median depending on their size, and how to print the name of the folder when finding it ?

Comment: You'll want to use the `stat`, `sort`, `wc` and `head` commands. Check their man pages

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- The title says you want the median-sized file, and the body suggests you want the median-sized directory.  I'll assume you mean directory.
- The directories are exactly one level deep - that is, you have directories `a`, `b`, `c` etc., but not `a/x`.
- If multiple directories have the same size, you are happy with the result being any one of them.
- There are exactly 99 directories.

If any of these assumption is incorrect, please say and I'll try to update the answer.

The command `du` will tell you the size of everything in each directory, printing for each directory the size and the name.  This will give you 100 lines: your 99 directories and one for the parent directory.

The command `sort -g` can sort the results in order of the numeric first field, which is the size.  The median of 99 results will now be at the 50th line.

The command `tail` can select the 50th line.

So combine these:

```
cd ~/wherever/
du | sort -g | tail -n +50
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Im sorry for my english, its my 3rd language so its kinda hard explaining what I really need. Theres 99 files with different sizes. I need to know which one is at the median depending of its size of course. I think your answer is the right one, once I get home from work i will try it and let you know  how it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of whatever you are counting and count the lines. The following works for both directories and files (replace $* with whatever you want to count):

```
    du -s $* | wc -l
```

You said that this in your case is 99. Divide by 2 and add 1 to get the order number of the median file/folder. In your case this is 50.

Now extract the line containing the median size file/folder:

```
    du -s $* | sort -n | tail -n +50 | head -1
```

(note that "du -s" does not include a file or directory added twice, for example "du -s /etc /etc/passwd" returns only a summary for /etc)